# How to reload (refresh) the WebView content by clicking a button? KOTLIN

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, kotlin, reload

I want to reload ( refresh ) the content of my WebView by clicking on a button , i tried this code but it's not working :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view)
    val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webv)
    val url: String = intent.getStringExtra("targetURL") ?: ""
    webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    webView.loadUrl(url)
    btn_go_back.setOnClickListener(
            webView.reload(url}
}
```

the error is here :

[image]

Comment: `webView.loadUrl(webView.GetUrl());`

Comment: i want to refrech the content of the web View and that does not working inside the setOnClickListener check it please

Comment: second i'm asking about using Kotlin

Comment: @HonEyMonEy Problem is "}". remove it after url in the last line! because you'll need two "}" for onCreate and Activity and not three.